# Update a javascript variable with the value in form-text field

Tags: html, textbox, submit

I create a D3 bar chart that where the input data is from a range of generation inside a json file.
I want to create a form with two text fields where i can insert the range and then update the chart.

The first form update the ST variabll and update the page, that is OK.
The next step is update the range os the  charts but without refresh the page, so the form1 should be "static".
I try to repeat the same procedure for the myfor2 and the variables are not updated.

```
 <form name="myform1" action="#" method="get" style="position: relative; top:10px;width:300px;margin-left:-70px;" > 
Input the St number<br />
<input type="text" name="StNumber" id="StNumber" value="9" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Set Value" /><br /> 
</form>

<form name="myform2" action="#" method="get" style="position: relative; top:10px"> 
Input the start generation<br />
<input type="text" name="GenStart" id="GenStart" value="2000" /><br />
Input the final generation<br />
<input type="text" name="GenFinal" id="GenFinal" value="2400" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Set Value" /><br /> 
</form>
```

Function that update the form one, that is ok:

```
function setValue(){ 
      var url=window.location+'';
      if(url.indexOf('?StNumber=')){
        var StNumber=parseInt(url.split('?StNumber=')['1']);
      if(StNumber>0 && isNaN(StNumber)==false){
          document.getElementById('StNumber').value = StNumber;
          StID = String(StNumber);
        }
        }else{
          StID = "9";
       }

      } 

    setValue();
```

Any sugestion!

Regards

http://jsfiddle.net/bnACW/425/

I need to update the javascript variables independently.
in myform1 I update the StID and set the value the variable are saved;
Then: in the myfor2 I update the endGen or StartGen or even the two at the same time ad set and the variablesare updated as the chart that need this two variables.

Comment: please tell me clearly what you need are show js fiddle

Comment: I update with more information and the jsfiddle

Comment: Hey u need to change the textbox values using jquery

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct, you just want to perform a JS action when the second button is pressed. Right now the second button is submitting your form because the input value of the button is set to "submit", change it to "button" to prevent the form submission, then you can add an onclick event and fire the desired function.

```
<input type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="setValue()" /><br />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, in yor opinion the solution is: create a new function that update the myform changed the tyoe and add onclick opition?
This will solve the problems with the refresh?

Comment: Yes, the page is refreshing because you are submitting the form, despite the fact that the action is set to "#", by changing the input type to "button" and then using an onlclick the page won't get refreshed anymore and you will be able to perform any js variable update on the client side.

Comment: I do this and nothing happens in my page, any suggestion?

Comment: Does the setValue function gets fired?